# How to find a node with particular role from a cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am writing a recipe for setting up a load balancer. I need to know the IP of the node that has the "role[wp_wasya]", or some other node(s) that has/have a certain role. I see online that there are ways to get a node by name, is there a way to get a node by searching its roles?

Answer (score 2):

```
app_nodes = search( :node, "role:#{ whatever_role }" )
app_node = app_nodes[0]
```

Comment: Correct. If you also want to search in the expanded run list (roles/recipes included from other roles), then search for `roles:#{whatever_role}`.

Answer (score 0):

This search will return only the first node in the result set.

```
app_nodes = search( :node, "role:#{ whatever_role }" )
app_node = app_nodes[0]
```

It will also use Ruby string interpolation (`#{}`), so you probably don't need that if you're specifying a particular role (`wp_wasya`). It is better to use the `roles` attribute for the search though, as that will return nodes that have the role nested.

If you're looking for multiple nodes, and only want to return the IP address:

```
app_servers = search(:node, "roles:wp_wasya").map {|n| n['ipaddress']}
```

This will be an array of IP address strings. For example, we can test this in the `chef-shell`:

```
chef > app_servers = search(:node, "roles:wp_wasya").map {|n| n['ipaddress']}
 => ["10.13.37.20", "10.13.37.21"]
```

We can use `#map` because this `#search` will return an `Array` of `Chef::Node` objects, which behave like `Hash` (though aren't really `Hash`).